# Upper bounds for a sequence of integers

Tags: integer-sequences, catalan-numbers, growth-rate

Given $\alpha\geq0$ we consider the sequence
$$
C_k=k^\alpha\sum_{j=0}^{k-1}C_jC_{k-1-j}
$$
with $C_0=1$. I'm interested in upper bounds (in terms of $\alpha$) for such a sequence. I know that when $\alpha=0$ the previous sequence reduces to the Catalan numbers where the bound is

$$
O(4^k/k^{3/2}),
$$
but I wonder whether something is known for positive $\alpha$.

Comment: maybe $C_0=1$? they seem to be all equal to 0 now

Comment: That must be true- edited accordingly.

Comment: For $\alpha=1$, this sequence seems to be OEIS A000699.

Comment: Oh, yes, sorry. That 0 was a typo. Nad yes, when $\alpha=0$ that sequence is well-known.